# Docker no basic auth credentials after succesfull login

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I've moved to linux (pop_os 21.04) on my desktop and I'm having some issues with docker.
When I'm trying to run docker-compose to pull an image from a private registry I'm getting:

```
ERROR: Head "https://my.registry/my-image/manifests/latest": no basic auth credentials
```

Of course before running this command I've ran:
`docker login https://my.registry.com -u user -p pass`
which returns

```
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /home/user/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
```

And my config.json in my .docker folder show my credentials

```
 {
    "auths": {
        "my.registry.com": {
            "auth": "XXXXX"
        }
    }
}
```

To install docker I've followed instructions on their page https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

And my version is:
Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d

The same command ran on a macos system with Docker version 20.10.8 runs without any issues so I my password and all the urls are correct for sure.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reinstalled the whole thing again as the docker page states, didn't work, so I uninstalled it and proceeded to install snap version, that didn't work neither and finally I removed it and went with simple apt-get install docker.io and it works like a charm! I don't know why it didn't work previously but I won't lose more sleep over it.

Answer (score 2):

The login commands is

```
docker login my.registry.com
```

Without the `https://` in front of the host. If you still have auth issues doing that:

- if the registry uses an unknown TLS certificate, load that certificate on the host and restart the docker engine
- if the registry is http instead of https, configure it as an insecure registry on `/etc/docker/daemon.conf`
- if the login is successful, but the pull fails, verify your user has access to the specific repo on the registry
- double check your password was correctly entered
- check for a network proxy intercepting the request (the `http_proxy` variable)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tried login with no https:// at the front but that didn't work either, however I've made it work again (accepted answer).

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue and my problem was that i logged in without sudo and afterwards tried to run containers with sudo priviledges.

So the solution for me was to run
`sudo login ...` and afterwards `sudo docker compose up -d`.

Answer (score -1):

On Ubuntu 20.x, I observed that the credentials are stored in `home/<username>/snap/docker/1125/.docker/config.json`.

If older credentials are stored in $HOME/.docker/config.json, they are not used by `docker pull`. Verify if docker is indeed picking up the credentials from the right config.json location.

Comment: I don't use snap version of docker, as stated above I installed it as specified on the docker page.